# Wikipedia Onebox breaks formatting

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, onebox

It seems our Wikipedia onebox doesn't know what to do with Wikipedia's style markup:

[image]

[This was the linked article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fringe_characters#September_.28The_Observer.29). It's catching the Table of Contents here, which is also annoying, but Wikipedia's style markup should probably be dropped from Onebox.

Comment: related (and essentially the same issue): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80629/numbers-mysteriously-stripped-from-inlined-wikipedia-articles-in-chat/80631#80631

Comment: @balpha huh, but if it's overzealously stripping that formatting, why's it ignoring this formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing a spring clean up.

This bug seems fixed now and I can't repro it.