# Oneboxing Wikipedia includes processing instructions like __NOTOC__

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox, wikipedia

Someone oneboxed the [Wikipedia Poblano article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poblano) in chat, and it showed up with **NOTOC** in front:

[image: Oneboxed "Poblano" showing __NOTOC__]

`__NOTOC__` is a MediaWiki processing instruction, of course, and really ought not show up in chat. (Also, that's seriously the wrong image, but I believe there are already bug reports on that.)

Comment: If I recall correctly, the image/picture selection algorithm is just "find the biggest one on the page and use that."

Comment: @PopularDemand the wrong image bug is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103244/wikipedia-chat-one-boxing-doesnt-always-pick-the-correct-image-from-the-article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now [fixed](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2211183#2211183), thanks to  [Wikipedia's TextExtract API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80631/115866).