# Incorrect oneboxing for Wikipedia page

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox, wikipedia

[This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U_and_non-U_English) is not displaying properly when oneboxed in chat:

> [image]

[image]

Comment: This is a stellar example of the community editing process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now [fixed](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2211212#2211212), thanks to  [Wikipedia's TextExtract API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80631/115866).