# Chat misses some words when oneboxing Wikipedia info

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

Did you know Australia was home to megafauna 40-50,000 years ago? They were huge! Our [Giant Wombat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diprotodon), which is very appropriately named, was a wombat that stood taller than an adult. So too did our largest kangaroo, the [Procoptodon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procoptodon).

If these facts are terrifying to you, it's okay. They went extinct around the time humans arrived here, so they have your back. So does the chat onebox mechanism, which will handily erase all terrifying facts.

[image: an excerpt of the procoptodon from wikipedia, with height and weight removed. Click to visit the chat message.]

But really, the chat probably shouldn't do that. They are extinct, and we can handle it.

Comment: That seems to be it, I just noticed the measurements are from a template.

Comment: Yeah, we all miss dupes sometimes, even yours truly. :) But it is all good, having dupes around help future visitors to find it more easily.

Comment: I had fun writing this one up at least. :)

Comment: Indeed, and got shiny 15 repz!

Comment: Fixed now: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaUXq.png (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80631/115866)